# convert a string of list to a list in erlang

Tags: string, list, type-conversion, erlang

so far I cannot find any one who has had the same problem as mine:

- input: "['atom_with_special_CHARACTERS_like@123']"
- output: ['atom_with_special_CHARACTERS_like@123']

just that, but after spending all this morning till noon, trying mixing something like: string:tokens, list_to_tuple, erl_parse... I cannot find any solution...
I know I'm getting close to the output, but just cannot really get it done.
could you please let me have some idea please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1> Parse = fun(S) -> {ok, Ts, _} = erl_scan:string(S), {ok, Result} = erl_parse:parse_term(Ts ++ [{dot,1} || element(1, lists:last(Ts)) =/= dot]), Result end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.99386804>
2> L = "['atom_with_special_CHARACTERS_like@123', 'you mean[like, this%']".
"['atom_with_special_CHARACTERS_like@123', 'you mean[like, this%']"
3> Parse(L).
[atom_with_special_CHARACTERS_like@123,
 'you mean[like, this%']
4> Parse("  [foo, bar,\n baz, 'q u ux'   ]   ").
[foo,bar,baz,'q u ux']
5> Parse("{you, [can, 'write any', term, 123, 3.5, yep]}").
{you,[can,'write any',term,123,3.5,yep]}
6> Parse("even_end_with_dot.").                            
even_end_with_dot
```

Comment: Thank you !! That's indeed what I need. :)
Thanks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
drop_first_last(Str) ->
    lists:reverse(tl(lists:reverse(tl(Str)))).

parse(Str) ->
    R = drop_first_last(Str), 
    [list_to_atom(drop_first_last(E)) || E <-string:tokens(R,",")].
```

calling parse function:

```
pokus:parse("['atom_with_special_CHARACTERS_like@123']").
```

output:

```
[atom_with_special_CHARACTERS_like@123]
```

or with multiple values:

```
pokus:parse("
['atom_with_special_CHARACTERS_like@123','another_atom@111']").
```

output:

```
[atom_with_special_CHARACTERS_like@123,another_atom@111]
```